# JPA TableGenerator update from another system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm having a table which has a primary key which is generated with table generator:

@TableGenerator(name = "resourceIdGenerator", table = "SEQUENCE", pkColumnName = "NAME", pkColumnValue = "resource_type_id", valueColumnName = "NEXTID", allocationSize = 1)
and it works fine.

However, I have another system(non-java) that modifies the same table from time-to-time by inserting new records into it. I'm wondering is it possible to update the values of this table generator of mine from another system that is not using JPA? Or the JPA maintains this by its own and it's the only one which manages the tablegenerator table?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but tableGenerator has not anything to do with the records inserted in the database, it is only generating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA can't magically use a table and forbid anyone else to use it. If you use the same strategy in your other system as the one used by Hibernate to generate your IDs, there's no reason it wouldn't work.

Since the allocation size is 1, you probably just need to start a new transaction, `select for update` the appropriate row of the sequence table, get its value and increment it by 1.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did exactly, but I really hoped that JPA in some magical way uses the tablegenerator and updates it accordingly when somebody tries to insert into the table, without I to have to care for incrementation of the key. I even tried to search whether there aren't some store procedures stored by JPA in the DB and use them, but no. However I'm now thinking to make such store procedure which to increment the key.

Comment: Such a strategy would be extremely inefficient, and would cause concurrency problems. It would need to get the max ID from the entity table at each insert. And the sequence table would not have any purpose anymore.